# Parent and Child objects in Pascal

Tags: object, freepascal, delphi

I have Parent object

```
type PNode=^Node;
     Node=Object
        Left,Right:PNode;
        Balance:integer;
        Function Is_Greater(Node1:PNode);
      end;
```

and a child object of object Node

```
Type ChildNode=object(Node);
        X:integer;
       end;
```

and I have 2 pointers P,Q:PNode and use command

```
P^:=Q^;
```

but it doesn't change the X value of node P.
Is there a way I can do that, without using pointers to child objects ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual method that you override in the child.

```
 type 
   PNode = ^TNode;
   TNode = object
               Constructor Init;
               procedure assign(t:pNode); virtual;
              end;

    PChildNode=^TChildNode;
    TChildNode = Object(TNode)
               x:integer;
               procedure assign(t:pNode); virtual;
               end;


 Constructor TNode.Init;
 begin
 end;
 procedure TNode.Assign(t:pNode); 
 begin
 // assign the tnode fields in t to the fields of self
 end;

 procedure TChildNode.Assign(t:pNode); 
 begin
   inherited Assign(t); // parent's fields first
   // we don't have Delphi's "IS" here, so can't test if t really is a pchildnode.
   x:=pchildnode(t)^.x;
 end;

function CreateChildNode(x:integer):PNode;
var chld : pChildNode;
begin
 chld:=new(PChildNode,Init); chld^.x:=x;
 createchildnode:=chld;
end;

// below this no knowledge of TChildnode except for printing.
var p1,p2 : PNode;

begin
 p1:=createchildnode(10);
 p2:=createchildnode(5);
 // p2^ must be equal to P1^ or derive from it. 
 // See comment in TChildNode.assign
 p1^.assign(p2); 
 writeln(pchildnode(p1)^.x);
end.
```

Note that in the equivalent *Delphi* dialect (CLASS) code, which you **SHOULD** use, you can test if the incoming element of assign really is a tchildnode using the **IS** operator

Looking at FPC's packages/tv and objects unit sources is a good resource to learn  the older TP dialect.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but your code is still contains the error: `TChildNode.Assign(t:TNode)` and `x:=t.x;` where `t` have no `x` field because it have `TNode` type.

Comment: Correct. It was schematic only, I updated it with a working program.

Answer (score 1):

The `X` field was not changed because `PNode` (and `TNode`) have not `X` field. Here is working code with some explanations and use cases:

```
program Project1;

type

    { TNode }

    PNode = ^TNode;
    TNode = object
        a: Integer;
        procedure assign(t:TNode);
    end;

    { TChildNode }

    PChildNode = ^TChildNode;
    TChildNode = object(TNode)
        x: Integer;
        // Overload parent method for the new type
        // Parent method still available via inherited (see below)
        procedure assign(t:TChildNode); overload;
    end;

{ TNode }

procedure TNode.assign(t: TNode);
begin
    a := t.a;
end;

{ TChildNode }

procedure TChildNode.assign(t: TChildNode);
begin
    inherited assign(t); // Call parent method to assign inherited fields values
    x := t.x;
end;

var
    n: TNode;
    cn1, cn2: TChildNode;

    pn, pcn2: PNode;
    pcn1: PChildNode;

begin
    n.a := 10;

    cn1.a := 11;
    cn1.x := 12;

    cn2.a := 21;
    cn2.x := 22;

    Writeln(cn1.a: 10, cn1.x: 10);

    cn1.assign(n);
    //cn1 := n; // Error here, type incompatibility
    Writeln(cn1.a: 10, cn1.x: 10);

    cn1.assign(cn2);
    Writeln(cn1.a: 10, cn1.x: 10);

    cn2.x := 44;
    // Actually this code works like previous
    cn1 := cn2;
    cn2.a := 55;
    Writeln(cn1.a: 10, cn1.x: 10);

    Readln;

    pn := New(PNode);
    pcn1 := New(PChildNode);
    pcn2 := New(PChildNode); // Here we assign PChildNode object to the variable with type PNode

    pn^.a := 10;

    pcn1^.a := 11;
    pcn1^.x := 12;

    pcn2^.a := 21;
    PChildNode(pcn2)^.x := 22; // This explicit conversion is necessary because PNode type of the pcn2 variable

    Writeln(pcn1^.a: 10, pcn1^.x: 10);

    //pcn1^.assign(pn^);
    //pcn1^ := pn^; // Error here, type incompatibility
    PNode(pcn1)^ := pn^;
    Writeln(pcn1^.a: 10, pcn1^.x: 10);

    // Here is X value does not changed because it is absent in the pcn2^ have TNode type
    // and assign method of the TNode will be called
    pcn1^.assign(pcn2^); 
    Writeln(pcn1^.a: 10, pcn1^.x: 10);

    // This code works well
    pcn1^ := PChildNode(pcn2)^;
    pcn2^.a := 55;
    Writeln(pcn1^.a: 10, pcn1^.x: 10);

    Readln;
end.
```

You can play with this code to learn more about objects behavior.

Comment: pcn1^.assign  still adds information that pcn1 is a p/tchildnode to the business code.The virtual method stuff fixes that, but misses the IS operator to make it safe.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort The missing of ability to check the actual type of the parameter is the main reason why i am used overloaded method instead of virtual. However it seems asker has lost any interest to his question.

Comment: There are ways around it btw, using VMT trickery, but that will be compiler specific. See sourcecode of tobject.is_object.  in TP times it was simply used without saveguards, but there it wasn't used as part of the automated persistence, like in Delphi, making it more under the programmers control.  Maybe we need a simple inheritsof/from method to avoid new code depending on that. OTOH not much new TP object code is written

Comment: Just for fun, evolution of OOP in Pascal: [http://pastebin.com/mvSJg7SH](http://pastebin.com/mvSJg7SH)